# OSX Uninstall via terminal a cUrl Installation

Tags: macos, curl, terminal

I've installed clamp thru this:

```
$ curl http://jide.github.io/clamp/install.sh | sh
```

( Followed this instructions: https://jide.github.io/clamp/ )

Now I have it installed, I found out is not working and is not exactly what I wanted, so I want to uninstall it. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the code, it has not done much but created `/usr/local/clamp/` and then soft-linked `/usr/local/clamp/clamp` to  `/usr/local/bin/clamp`.

Please refer the [Line #64 & #65 of install.sh](https://github.com/jide/clamp/blob/gh-pages/install.sh#L64-65)

You can delete the files as part of manual uninstall

```
$ rm -rf /usr/local/clamp/
$ rm -rf /usr/local/bin/clamp
```